SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext' is causing stuck queries in Django 3
SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext' is causing stuck queries in Django 3. If I kill it, all the other queries will proceed.
In this similar question (SELECT typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'citext'), it is indicated that this is now being cached in later versions of Django. But why is my app still querying it? Is there a configuration that needs to be enabled so that it will be cached?
Thanks.
